# Error on second step delete of object item

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $("body").on("click", ".delete_human", function(){
        var custom_tdid = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $(".peoples_data .xls-people-"+custom_tdid).hide(400 , function() {$(".peoples_data .xls-people-"+custom_tdid).remove()});
        console.log(people);
        for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
            if(people[i].tdid==custom_tdid)
            {
                delete people[i];
                delete people_to_parse[i];
                delete people_to_save_parse[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(people); 
    });
```

**Morkup:**

```
        var td1 = "<tr class='xls-people-"+custom_tdid+"'><td><div class='parse_name Photo-text-"+custom_tdid+"'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/3/picture'/></div></td>";
        var td2 = "<td><div class='parse_name ID-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_id+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='ID-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td3 = "<td><div class='parse_name Name-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_firstname+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='Name-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td4 = "<td><div class='parse_name Surname-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_lastname+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='Surname-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td5 = "<td><div class='parse_name Nickname-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_nickname+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='Nickname-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td6 = "<td><div class='parse_name Phone-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_phone+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='Phone-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td7 = "<td><div class='parse_name City-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_city+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='City-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td8 = "<td><div class='parse_name CountFriends-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_countfriends+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='CountFriends-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td9 = "<td><div class='parse_name Mail-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_mail+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='Mail-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td10 = "<td><div class='parse_name Avocation-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>"+custom_avocation+"</div><div class='parse_name1'><div class='switch demo3'><input type='checkbox' id='counters' class='Avocation-"+custom_tdid+"'><label><i></i></label></div></div></td>";
        var td11 = "<td><div class='parse_name Status-text-"+custom_tdid+"'>Wait to parse</div><button class='delete_human' data-id='"+custom_tdid+"'>DELETE</button></td></tr>";
        $(".peoples_data tbody").append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+td8+td9+td10+td11).hide().show('slow');
```

[image]

Comment: I am attach screen with debbuger

Comment: sorry where is `people` is declared? and markup also will be better.

Comment: you can look it on screen in debuger field. There are all you can find to resolve it. This trouble resolve easy for experience developer.

Comment: I think But markup will be better than guessing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57884/discussion-between-mritunjay-and-arthur-yakovlev).

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: Sorry, but no. All issue placed to topic.

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is removing the element by [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator, use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead, since `delete` still keeps the index with the value `undefined`, but `splice` actually removes the element from the array

```
$("body").on("click", ".delete_human", function(){
    var custom_tdid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(".peoples_data .xls-people-"+custom_tdid).hide(400 , function() {$(".peoples_data .xls-people-"+custom_tdid).remove()});
    console.log(people);
    for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
        if(people[i].tdid==custom_tdid)
        {
            people.splice(i, 1);
            people_to_parse.splice(i, 1);
            people_to_save_parse.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(people); 
});
```

**Debug**

You can see ( in your console output ) there is actually two elements in the array, but length still holding the value of 3, now you can realize where the error happens.

Comment: Thanks! I am do it `people.splice(i);` and this is was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop's constraint is people.length.  There is no guarantee that people_to_parse and people_to_save are the same length as people.

Comment: No, by my code garanted. So this is not solve my question, but thanks